# Lighthouse returned error: generic::internal: APP::1 status = crashed exit_code = 1

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

While checking the website speed [Here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftheocrtribe.com%2F&tab=mobile)
I am getting this error for desktop only.

`Lighthouse returned error: generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was occurring due to some invalid lazyloading scripts

Answer (score 1):

when running the test I get `Details: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`

This often happens when you have something like ModSec installed on your server and it stops multiple page requests in a short amount of time. (as the page is requested twice in quick succession to run the desktop and mobile tests).

The other possible cause is that your site allows people to view it without SSL. There could be an error thrown if PSI is trying to request the non-SSL version while you have hard-coded SSL paths.

Try making sure your site always redirects to the SSL version and see if the problem persists.